# Science Fiction Novel where Dinosaurs are still alive in the Modern Day

Tags: story-identification, young-adult, dinosaurs

The story follows a brother and sister (I think) and they have a relative who has modern dinosaur DNA or an egg or something. There is a scandal and they end up in the jungle somewhere where they have to eat an andaconda. I am pretty sure I read this about 6 years ago, but I am not sure if it was new then. There are not a lot of Dinos, and I am pretty sure the kids relative wants to capture the dino for some reason. The Dinos are hidden in the jungle so not a lot of ppl know they exist.

Answer (score 3):

Wild guess: [Cryptid](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptid_Hunters) [Hunters](http://www.barnesandnoble.com/w/cryptid-hunters-roland-smith/1100552461?ean=9780786851621) (2 links)

From B&N summary

> After their parents are lost in an accident, thirteen-year old twins
>   Grace and Marty are whisked away to live with their Uncle Wolfe-an
>   uncle that they didn't even know they had! The intimidating Uncle
>   Wolfe is an anthropologist who has dedicated his life to finding
>   cryptids, mysterious creatures believed to be long extinct. Twins,
>   Grace and Marty, along with a mysterious uncle, are dropped into the
>   middle of the Congolese jungle in search of their missing
>   photojournalist parents.

It seems to match your description (except with eating an anaconda, although there might have been one. I don't remember. It has been years since I read the book):

- brother and sister (twins)
- modern dinosaur eggs
- mess in Democratic Republic of Congo (scandal?)
- hidden in jungle in DR of Congo
- >6 years ago (published 2005)
- not a lot of dinosaurs (2 eggs)
- the family of the children are involved (somewhat spoilers)